# Azure Universal Artifacts download of large package fails

Tags: azure-cli, azure-artifacts

I'm testing out Azure Artifacts using Universal packages. For relatively large universal packages things are fine (tested using 1GB and 4GB sized packages) but once I tried one that is just over 20GB the download fails with a 403 error. Originally I raised the issue [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/azure-artifacts-download-of-large-package-fails/1308520) and after a while when they couldn't help raised it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16956). I've tried using a PAT rather than az login. I've tried using a local build agent rather than the CLI direct however this gave the same error as the CLI.
It feels like I've got around 30 minutes of download time before something expires however I can't prove that. The error log is attached to both linked issues but the top part is

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).) (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.).)
```

Last time I tried the download the version I was using was using Windows 10 powershell and:

```
azure-cli 2.18.0
core 2.18.0
telemetry 1.0.6
Extensions:
azure-devops 0.18.0
```

Has anyone managed a download of a universal package using Azure Artifacts that was larger than 22GB ? They say that up to 1TB is supported - anyone got 100GB to work?

Thanks for your time,
Simon

Comment: How did you publish the 22GB Universal Artifacts to Azure Artifact? Could you share the detailed step you downloaded the artifact? Try to add `--debug` argument to prints more information about CLI operations.

Comment: Hi to download the artifact I used `az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/XXX --project="Test" --scope project --feed TestFeed --name ansible-media3 --version 2.3.2 --path fred` which was almost the same command to upload. In the first link ([here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/azure-artifacts-download-of-large-package-fails/1308520) I have attached the debug log - I don't think I can attach files in stackoverflow.

Comment: Comment was to long - [here](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B788f4da23177436f82362ef86b4a9c70637462236435058622_downloadlogwithdebug.txt&tid=788f4da23177436f82362ef86b4a9c70637462236435058622) is the debug log file

Comment: I've noticed in the log "Downloaded 20,250.7 MB out of 25,479.5 MB (79%)", did you always get error when downloaded about 79%, or get error about 30 mins after downloading?

Comment: As I'm working from home my bandwidth isn't great so its about 70mbps (its not bad though). My guess was that was how much I could download in about 30 mins. I haven't managed to download more than that and I've not managed to download for longer than 30 mins. Note upload speed for me is 20 mbps so the upload took much longer and as far as I can tell worked ok

Comment: I'm afraid you need to wait for azure-cli team's response. Azure Artifacts is a highly-scalable artifact service. In the course of everyday development, you shouldn’t need to worry about limits on size and quantity of packages you store. However, the service does have some architectural limits and also some limits imposed by the client tools (e.g. nuget.exe) it integrates with.

Comment: I've only been waiting on them for 2 weeks so it can't be long :)

Comment: Ok 4 weeks :( It seems the MS github issues aren't getting the same amount of focus as their develop community ones or indeed stackoverflow